# 70's or 80's comic/graphic novel collection of short stories featuring one entry about plant life taking over a marooned spaceman

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to recall an illustrated comic book/graphic novel collection of sci-fi short stories from 40+ years ago. One of the stories in this book was about a marooned spaceman who crashed on a planet, and eventually his helmet cracks and at first he thinks everything is ok but then some kind of plant spores in the atmosphere take hold and he is rapidly covered in some kind of moss or lichen, lungs-first and then eventually everywhere and all over his wrecked ship too.

Potentially relevant info:

- comic was full color
- American or possibly British
- this particular story was a horror or light-horror angle on sci-fi
- one panel toward the end depicted the moss/lichen growing out of his mouth and choking him to death in a particularly horrific image

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I can think of a number of classic stories with settings like that (often Venus back when people thought it might have life), but none of the ones I've checked appear to have comic adaptations.

Comment: I almost suggested Creepshow, but the guy taken over by plant life in that was an earthbound farmer, not a spaceman.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 unfortunately I don't recall if it was a single-issue comic book, rather than some kind of trade paperback collection. I think one of the other short stories in the book may have been related to the late '70s Battlestar Galactica series, because I can recall a panel with ships that definitely looked like vipers and cylons. But I've looked into the Marvel comic book run of Battlestar and I don't see anything in there that fits this. Is it possible that there was a Battlestar short story included in some other "shorts" anthology comic?